# How to submit a form both to the page and an iframe?

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, form-submit

I have a simple HTML form like this:

```
<form id="simple-form" method="get" action="">
    <input name="year" type="number" value="">
    <input name="month" type="number" value="">
    <input name="day" type="number" value="">
    <button type="submit" id="potvrdi" onclick="return submitForms()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click submit button, it triggers JS function. I tried to make JS function to submit form to multiple targets (to index page and an iframe) but it is not working. Here is my Javascript:

```
function submitForms() {

    var formular = document.getElementById('simple-form');

    formular.action='index.php';
    formular.target='_self';
    formular.submit();

    formular.action='my-map.php';
    formular.target='map-frame';
    formular.submit();

    return true;
}
```

I succed to submit only to a page or to an iframe, but not to both. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: if you submit with `target='_self'`, won't that cause a navigation and remove the iframe anyway?

Comment: A form refreshed the page. So when it get's executed it will do one, but not both.

Comment: But how to prevent it? I have tried with return function onclick...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the moment you submit to '_self' the page is instantly refreshed which doesn't give the iframe a chance to process the form data. Hence you can submit only to the iframe or '_self' which refreshes the page.

One way would be to use AJAX to handle the '_self' request, stopping the page from refreshing.

EDIT:

If you're only using pure JS (as opposed to using jQuery), then check this out: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

For jQuery, as @mheiber mentioned, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post